# Custom Font in Tabbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fonts, uitabbarcontroller

Hey, 
is there a way to set the tabbar's font to e.g. Chalkboard? I've seen the question for the font size and tried it with font, but the loop wouldn't work out.

If there's no way for a custom font, is it possible to remove all text and make the tabbar's item covering the whole tab? Or can I somehow put a imageView on top of the tabbar and use the tabs "through" that image?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it would be good to explain what's your exact intention as it's not completely clear what you want to achieve. Generally, it's not recommended to subclass/override UITabBar and its items, but maybe there's some better way how to make what you want - just tell us what it is.

Comment: @Matthes I just need a custom appearance of the tabbar. The "easiest" customization is to have the tabbar display it's text in chalkboard font. The "best" would be if I could have each tab "covered" by an image. Not an icon but an image that coveres the whole tab, just like a background image for a button. Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found myself an amazing and very easy tutorial to achieve exactly what I need.
For further reference and for all, that might need that too, here's the link

[Part 1](http://www.rumexit.co.uk/2010/07/how-to-customise-the-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application-part-1-of-2/)

[Part 2](http://www.rumexit.co.uk/2010/11/how-to-customise-the-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application-part-2-of-2/#more-143)

Comment: Try not to post link answers. If the links break then the accepted answer suddenly becomes useless. Instead try to post the basic content of the link and then post the links as extras to enhance your answer

Answer (score 5):

Put in the AppDelegate.m under:

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Here is the code:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: [[UITabBarItem appearance] titleTextAttributesForState:UIControlStateNormal]];
[attributes setValue:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:10] forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 13 there is a bug with `UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes` method, so we need to do workaround like this:

```
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12),
                      NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]

    let appearance = UITabBarItem.appearance()
    appearance.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = attributes
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.badgeBackgroundColor = .blue
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = attributes
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.badgeBackgroundColor = .blue
        tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    }
```

If you only set appearance `tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance` on iOS 13 you'll still have a bug, but the other one