# Custom font not working on iPad 5.0 & 5.1

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-simulator, ios6, xcode4.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom Font in Tabbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206069/custom-font-in-tabbar)

I am having troubles displaying custom font in TabBarItem.

My whole app is using custom font.
But only the TabBarItem font is not displaying my custom font.
It is working on iPhone simulator iOS 5, 5.1 and 6.
But for iPad simulator,the custom font for TabBarItem is only working on iOS 6.

My code to set the TabBarItem is

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[UIColor lightTextColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
[UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomFont"  size:16.0], UITextAttributeFont,
nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Is there different way to set TabBarItem custom font for iOS 5 and 5.1?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the way you load the font, `[UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomFont.ttf"  size:16.0]` is the name of the font file not the name of the font.

Your `CustomFont.ttf` should contain a font, for example `CustomFont-Regular`. Then you can load that font by: `[UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomFont-Regular"  size:16.0]`.

It looks like Apple made some changes in iOS 6 that will allow you to load a font by it's file name.

Comment: Umm sorry I didn't use "CustomFont.ttf". I use the font name itself. It is strange that it works on all the iPhone simulator.But for iPad simulator, only iOS 6. Help me ~ thanks :)